# Neovim: how to show whitespace

Tags: neovim

I tried the `:set list` command, but it does not work. When I run `:set listchars`, it outputs `listchars=tab:> ,trail:-,nbsp:+`, but whitespace is never visible. I have done very little to customize this, so I am confident that this is not some user error that I have introduced -- it is basically a fresh installation (on Ubuntu 22.04) with four custom key maps.

Edit: [it appears to be capable of this](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/8fe9f41f7f9da2009d11855ec0548b9dbe548a69/runtime/syntax/whitespace.vim#L1), but I cannot find any working instructions for enabling whitespace visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The trick was that the space in `listchars=tab:> ,trail:-,nbsp:+` needed to be escaped as such: `listchars=tab:>\ ,trail:-,nbsp:+`. But also, it did not actually show the spaces, and it looked ugly for tabs, so I changed it to this: `set listchars=space:·,tab:->\` .

I put that and `set list` in my init.vim file, and now it shows whitespaces properly.